# Rule don't update with vuelidate in composable vuejs3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuelidate

I want to use composable in vuejs3 to group some vuelidate logic but I'm encountering a problem with rules update when I want to validate dates

Here is a github repro, it will be much more easier to explain the problem with it
https://github.com/lou-theo/bug-vuelidate-composable-dates

In this example I have an input to set a dynamic threshold and then another input using this threshold for a min value rule

As we can see, this is working perfectly well with numbers but with dates, the threshold stay on the first value entered by the user

I guess I'm missing the understanding of some deep reactivity rules but I haven't found where the problem lies, that's why I'm asking for help